# Spyder:How to enter command line arguments for use in integrated console

Tags: macos, console, command-line-interface, spyder

I like the integration in Spyder (5.3.3 on MacOS) except for one thing. It doesn't facilitate passing command line arguments to a program to debug in the integrated console.  The "Run--> Configuration per file" menu item requires that I "Execute in an external system terminal" before it enables the option to enter command line arguments.  My workaround is to run the program once with the "green start arrow", then in the console use the Up arrow to recover the runfile command and edit into that command an *args='arg1,arg2..*.' parameter.
That works, but is cumbersome.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,  this is a kludge, but it works, sort of.  I have a fresh install of Anaconda that comes with Spyder 5.3.3, so this is the latest and greatest.  The Run Configurationper File editor won't let me add commandline parameters unless I'm willing to launch into an external shell, which is too sucky for words.  My workaround is to launch it opnce and ignore the errors associated with having no command line parameters; then using the up arrow key on the keybooard in th iPython console I brung back the "runfile" command, insert an args parameter, press Enter and enjoy the fruits of my labor.  Here's what I mean, where the program s\is simply " print(sys.argv

```
runfile('/Users/daryl/demo.py', wdir='/Users/daryl', args = ' a b c')
['/Users/daryl/demo.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Although I see you found a solution that works for you, I'd like to point out that there's no need to use an external terminal to pass command line options to Python scripts in Spyder. I understand that that would seem the case because the first `Command line options:` field is related to the `Execute in a system terminal` option, but below there's another field called exactly the same that works for IPython consoles.

Comment: However, I understand this could be very confusing due to the way the `Run configuration per file` dialog is designed. So, if you have suggestions on how we could improve it, please open an issue in [this Github repository](https://github.com/spyder-ide/ux-improvements/).